# linkedin api v2: "Not enough permissions to access" for /people

Tags: api, linkedin-api

My question is similar for [Linkedin v2 api: Not enough permissions to access: GET /countriesV2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49851623/linkedin-v2-api-not-enough-permissions-to-access-get-countriesv2),  [LinkedIn V2 api: Not enough permissions to access /me GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46149484/linkedin-v2-api-not-enough-permissions-to-access-me-get),  [Not enough permissions to access /me GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363237/not-enough-permissions-to-access-me-get) and others, but works with **/v2/organizations/** endpoint (that's why I think the app is already applied for api: https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program).

That's not my app - my client's one.

My task is getting members' info, but any calls to **/v2/people/** endpoint fall.

The **r_basicprofile** permission is set and I no need for extra profile fields.

Now I see a couple of problems with linkedin REST API:

- most of examples are for v1
- v1 doesn't work at all
- links to the linkedin site (like https://developer.linkedin.com/comment/NNNNN#comment-NNNNN%23comment-NNNNN) mostly don't work (about 95-99%)
- I can't even call samples from developer.linkedin.com

I asked about this on linkedin help forum. I don't understand is this api works or not?

Does anyone have a successful experience with **/v2/people/** endpoint?

Comment: Do you still have issues with the above API endpoint or this question is no longer relevant?

Comment: I didn't checked. I changed my code logic and don't use API calls.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to use V2 apply to the partnership that is required.
but because you need only basic profile info try this :

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url,email-address,public-profile-url)?format=json
```

this will return the information of the person who is loggedin.
if you want information of another person try this:

```
 https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/[user_id]:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url,email-address,public-profile-url)?format=json
```

hopefully this works for you.

Comment: `This resource is no longer available under v1 APIs`. OK, I'll ask my client about appling to use v2. But why **/v2/organizations/** works? Or this endpoint doesn't need to be applied?

Comment: i am confused why you get this error, i used the same call, literaly 20 seconds ago.

and i check and i cant access organizations because i do not have any partnership with linkedin at this time see error here :
  
`{
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET-roleAssignee /organizationalEntityAcls",
    "status": 403
}`

so i think you have a different partnership with linkedin to access organizations but not the people api.

Comment: I am too. I rechecked organizations api a few hours ago - works correctly. I found many examples like you sent and none of them work for me. That's why I thought v1 api has been deprecated and doesn't work at all for now.

Comment: is it a possibilty you share a bit of code where you make an api call because i would like to see if you add anything weird to a V1 call.  
maybe your code can only allow V2 requests for some reason

Comment: the calls only v2 endpoints - no v1.
examples... just request like ```        uri: 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations', 
        qs, /* query params */
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer TOKEN`,
        },
        json: true,
```.
It's a nodejs app.

Comment: well to be honest, i have no clue what would be the problem.

but one thing to note is that we are currently also applying for a partnership and it can take up to a solid month befor you get any response (approved/denied).
so i would really check into the V1 API and get it to work , because the V1 api does still work, would save you alot of time.

Comment: thanks. I also asked about applying for partnership to app admins. we'll see.